# HTTP error 503. service unavailable when trying to run local host

Tags: iis, asp.net-identity, http-status-code-503, applicationpoolidentity

HTTP error 503. service unavailable when trying to run local host.
Default application pool is getting stopped everytime when trying to run local host.
IIS-->Application pools-->Default application pool-->advancedsettings-->Generate process model log entry-->identity has been set propwerly to corect credentials.
Also tried restarting the IIS.
Tried all solutions suggested in below link.

[https://windowsreport.com/http-error-503-service-unavailable/#:~:text=If%20HTTP%20error%20503%20the,it%20would%20resolve%20the%20issue.&text=Right%2Dclick%20on%20DefaultAppPool%20to,service%20is%20unavailable%20is%20gone](https://windowsreport.com/http-error-503-service-unavailable/#:%7E:text=If%20HTTP%20error%20503%20the,it%20would%20resolve%20the%20issue.&text=Right%2Dclick%20on%20DefaultAppPool%20to,service%20is%20unavailable%20is%20gone).
can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the following solutions:

- Click on application pools under the tree with your machine name, on the right side, click on advanced settings, in Process Model change the **"Load User Profile" to false**, Start your apllication and restart your IIS.
- In IIS go to the Application Pools under the Server, then find the correct application pool for your web site, and click on it. On the advanced settings menu to the right, select Identity and change it and enter new user and password. Click on your application pool again, and select recycle to restart it.

Comment: Try to use the [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85) to get the detailed cause of the error.